# fatal error in magento admin part add category

Tags: magento

I am facing one error in Magento Admin part, When I try to create a category it shows following fatal Error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Data\Tree\Dbp.php on line 331

```
 public function loadEnsuredNodes($category, $rootNode)
 {
    $pathIds = $category->getPathIds();
    $rootNodeId = $rootNode->getId();
    $rootNodePath = $rootNode->getData($this->_pathField);

    $select = clone $this->_select;
    $select->order($this->_table.'.'.$this->_orderField . ' ASC');
```

So can anyone help me? how to fix this issues? can anyone suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this SQL query and it should clean it right up :)

INSERT  INTO       `catalog_category_entity`(`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_set_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`POSITION`,`level`,`children_count`) VALUES (1,3,0,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1',1,0,1),(2,3,3,0,'2009-02-20 00:25:34','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1/2',1,1,0);
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_int`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,32,0,2,1),(2,3,32,1,2,1);
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,31,0,1,'Root Catalog'),(2,3,33,0,1,'root-catalog'),(3,3,31,0,2,'Default Category'),(4,3,39,0,2,'PRODUCTS'),(5,3,33,0,2,'default-category');

Comment: Thanks, you saved me :D

Answer (score 0):

UGH. Core code debugging. I have to do this all the time.

Put a try catch on that code and error_log the results.  It will give you a better idea of which line has the problem.  Check your php log for the results

```
public function loadEnsuredNodes($category, $rootNode)
 {
    try {
       $pathIds = $category->getPathIds();
       $rootNodeId = $rootNode->getId();
       $rootNodePath = $rootNode->getData($this->_pathField);

       $select = clone $this->_select;
       $select->order($this->_table.'.'.$this->_orderField . ' ASC');

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
```

If the error persists, then then try using the code in an isolated environment. Create a file test.php and put it in magento root.

```
<?php
   umask(0);
   require_once 'app/Mage.php';
   Mage::app('admin');
   echo "<PRE>";

   $category_id = 12;
   $rootNode = ??? load a root node what is this?

   $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
   var_dump($category->debug());

   $pathIds = $category->getPathIds();
   var_dump($pathIds);

   $rootNodeId = $rootNode->getId();
   var_dump($rootNodeId);
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

This answer

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity(entity_id,entity_type_id,attribute_set_id,parent_id,created_at,updated_at,path,POSITION,level,children_count) VALUES (1,3,0,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1',1,0,1),(2,3,3,0,'2009-02-20 00:25:34','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1/2',1,1,0);
INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_int(value_id,entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id,value) VALUES (1,3,32,0,2,1),(2,3,32,1,2,1); 
INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_varchar(value_id,entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id,value) VALUES (1,3,31,0,1,'Root Catalog'),(2,3,33,0,1,'root-catalog'),(3,3,31,0,2,'Default Category'),(4,3,39,0,2,'PRODUCTS'),(5,3,33,0,2,'default-category');
```

---

Helped me, thanx for saving my day!... but i had a table prefix in my database so
incase it don¨t work for anyone
change... all i belive 3 " INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity "
with `"INSERT INTO _add_your_database prefix here_catalog_category_entity`

and it should work... anyhow big thanx for the help!